# MongoDB find an array that is a subset of a query array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subset

I have a collection like

```
{ arr:[1] }
{ arr:[1,2] }
{ arr:[1,2,3] }
```

and I have a search array.

```
[1,2]
```

so I want to find all the documents that are subsets of the search array or match it.

the query here should return

```
{ arr:[1] }
{ arr:[1,2] }
```

Comment: i need to solve the exact same problem...were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly matching: `db.collection.find({ $or: [ {arr: [1,2] }, { arr:[1]} ] })`

If you add additional field which count amount of arr's elements, like that:

```
{ arr:[1], cnt: 1 }
{ arr:[1,2], cnt: 2 }
{ arr:[1,2,3], cnt: 3 }
```

you may use this query: `db.collection.find({ arr: { $in: [1,2] }, cnt: {$in:[1,2]} })`.

Next example in the last case: `db.collection.find({ arr: { $in: [1,2,3] }, cnt: {$in:[2,3]} })` will output:

```
{ "cnt" : 2, "arr" : [  1,  2 ] }
{ "cnt" : 3, "arr" : [  1,  2,  3 ] }
```